# What does apply_all_rows mean in SurveyMonkey API survey design?

Tags: surveymonkey

What does apply_all_rows mean below in a multiple_choice Survey Monkey question?  (The definition was retrieved via the SurveyMonkey v3 API; I do not have access to the original design.)  I think apply_all_rows makes sense with a matrix question.

I thought it would mean that every checkbox would get its own "Other" text field, but the text responses have the ID from the 'other' section, and are not repeated per row.  Also, I cannot find a way to make a Checkboxes question have an Other per checkbox when designing my own survey.

```
"sorting": null,
"family": "multiple_choice",
"subtype": "vertical",
"required": null,
"answers": {
  "other": {
    "id": "1569506482",
    "visible": true,
    "is_answer_choice": false,
    "apply_all_rows": true,
    "text": "If you answered yes to any of these, please describe:",
    "position": 0,
    "num_chars": 50,
    "error_text": "",
    "num_lines": 1
  },
  "choices": [
    {
      "visible": true,
      "text": "Option A",
      "position": 1,
      "id": "1569506411"
    },
    {
      "visible": true,
      "text": "Option B",
      "position": 2,
      "id": "1569506475"
    }
  ]
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct, the `apply_all_rows` only has affect on matrix type questions, where you get an other option in each row of the grid if it is set to `true`, otherwise there is only one other option at the end of the question.

I wasn't aware that it can be set to true for any other question type (perhaps only through the API). But for a normal multiple choice type question that option means nothing.

Comment: This is not the first time I have had to work around data that is inconsistent with the (returned) survey design :-(